# Getting the error callback from an $http get in an angular ui-router state resolve

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I require some data from a website for a state to work, so I put an http request in resolve.  However, if the request doesn't work, I can't seem to get any error message or anything to happen. The '$stateChangeError' callback doesn't work once a problem happens inside the $http callback.  'console.log' doesn't seems to print anything.  It's as if the get request's failure callback never happens.

```
resolve:{
    list-o-stuff: function($http, $rootScope){
        //throw 'test';
        //    ^that worked (it triggers '$stateChangeError')
        return $http.get('exampERROR!le.com').then( function(response){
            return response;
        }, function(response){
            console.log(response);
            //    that didn't do anything
            throw response;
            //    that didn't do anthing either
        });
    }
}
```

Bummer right.  I guess I'll try adding another console.log and do a hard refresh... ***POOF!*** as soon as I ctrl+F5, firefox decides to show all that stuff that the '$stateChangeError' broadcast was supposed to do. If I use firebug, breakpoints in this callback are never triggered. Why?  How can I debug like this?

Thanks,
    Kenkron

Comment: How does it behave on Chrome?

Comment: Can you share the error.

Comment: @obe I forgot to mention, on chrome, I never get the error messages

Comment: @Gary, the error is that I'm using an invalid URL.  It's message is whatever I put into the `$stateChangeError` broadcast.  (something like 'error switching from stateA to stateB')

Comment: Have you tried a different url? Possible put a plnk.co I will try to resolve it

Answer (score 0):

Bear in mind that in order for the callback to be executed, the $http request must return an error code outside the range of 200 - 299.

According to the AngularJS [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http):

"A response status code between 200 and 299 is considered a success status and will result in the success callback being called. Any response status code outside of that range is considered an error status and will result in the error callback being called. Also, status codes less than -1 are normalized to zero. -1 usually means the request was aborted, e.g. using a config.timeout. Note that if the response is a redirect, XMLHttpRequest will transparently follow it, meaning that the outcome (success or error) will be determined by the final response status code."

Comment: It's -1, so the error callback should definitely be called. Maybe it's doesn't time out until a page refresh?